# Is "fade apart" an idiomatic phrase for saying "die", "dying" or similar?

Tags: idiomatic-language, phrasal-verbs

> I apologize for any confusion earlier. It seems like you're looking
> for alternatives to "die" in phrasal form that ends with "apart."
> While this is a somewhat uncommon request and there may not be 30
> commonly used phrases that fit this criteria, I'll do my best to
> provide some options:
>
> > Fade apart
> > Wither apart
> > Perish apart
> > Expire apart
> > Succumb apart

This came from ChatGPT, and it's an unusual prompt, but the answers don't make any sense, I don't think any of them have a similar meaning to "die" and none of them are idiomatic. Maybe wither apart, but the others seem to be completely wrong.

Comment: None are idiomatic.  "Fade away" perhaps. There are lots of euphemisms for death https://www.mariecurie.org.uk/media/press-releases/poll-reveals-over-50-different-euphemisms-for-death/262947 No common one is ".... apart"   ChatGPT is just doing what you told it to do. It even warns you that these are not common expressions!

Comment: ChatGPT is so unreliable that it's not a good use of this site's time to answer whether it's correct or not. It's not a native speaker and it's not professional, so what it says isn't worth analyzing for correctness.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks us to correct an AI output.

Comment: The examples created are not natural because the prompt is asking for **30** phrasal verbs ending in *apart* that mean "to die". That's not an unusual prompt, it's a very unrealistic request.  Good luck asking that to any human user!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original prompt was unrealistic to begin with. That an AI obeyed the request and offered only mildly *plausible* solutions is the fault of the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. And not only is *fade apart* not an expression for *die*, it’s not even a coherent collocation. Fading has to do with becoming less prominent, less bright, whereas *apart* has to do with separation or division.